# Excel: Conditional Formatting based on ranges

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

Is there a way to highlight duplicate values if a range contains `2` or more values from a separate range?

If `A1:A5` contains any `2` or more of the same values from `B1:B5`

I've tried a number of different methods, all of which I'm getting wrong.

Should it be something akin to...

`if(a1:a5,b1,a1:a5,b2,a1:a5,b3,a1:a5,b4,a1:a5,b5)`

...or a nested `AND` function?

I'm not sure I'm wording it correctly.

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: Yes, I did try =or(a1:a5=b1,a1:a5=b2,a1:a5=b3,a1:a5=b4,a1:a5=b5) [applying it to the range of a1:a5] but this highlights results that are not in the range as well those that are.

Comment: I actually think you are trying to do this: https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/identifying-duplicate-values-in-an-excel-list which identifies duplicates. It uses `=COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1)` to determine if there is a duplicate

Comment: you say: `contains 2 or more values` . maybe need to check exist and count unique value! pretty potato :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF()), but you will need two rules one for A and another for B:

A:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5))>=2,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)))
```

B:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5))>=2,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you find `SUMPRODUCT` to be resource heavy @Scott Craner?

Comment: Not when only doing `5` countifs.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply - haven't been able to access my work computer since March. This worked for me - just got to remember how all the other functions work. Thanx again, Sam.